# Can Django REST Framework serializers be used for other web-frameworks?

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework, aiohttp

I want to use JSON serilization in my `aiohttp.web` application. But I haven't found any libraries for that task in `aiohttp` universe.

If there are any problem to use serilizers from `django-rest-ramework` with `aiohttp`?

Comment: I think you can fork DRF repo from the GitHub and customize with your code this can be possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django REST framework is very closely tied to django itself. You could probably hack a setup where you were able to use a little of DRF with aiohttp but you would obviously lose most of what DRF does: routing, db/model integration, views, viewsets,  authentication.

Much better to use one of the many other serialization and deserialization libraries available in python. I would recommend [pydantic](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic) (admission: I developed pydantic), but there are loads of other such libraries.

The power of DRF comes from it's completeness and first class integration with django. Without that it's not a good choice. It's also [very slow](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/47).

Comment: Thank you! `pydantic` looks very good, but it requires `Python3.6`. I don't know if my project would easily be ported to 3.6 . But you give me great idea at all!

Comment: No problem, @IlliaAnanich. To give you some hope: I ported a 100k line platform from 3.5 to 3.6 without a **single** change, if you're on 3.4 it's a different matter but if you're on 3.4 you'll want to upgrade soon anyway.

Comment: Hi @SColvin is there any way I could use pydentic model as drf serializers ?

Comment: Not exactly but I know there are a number of libraries that use pydantic with Django.